# Book recommendations for pre-press and printing a LaTeX document

Tags: xetex, books, pdfx, publishing, cmyk

I'm on the way to self-publishing a book I wrote in LaTeX. Now, I don't have any broader background in LaTeX other than scientific writing. However, I got this far that I now need to dive into the details of pre-press, the goal being a PDF document I can send to a print shop.

This is the current state: I used the `scrbook` class together with XeLaTeX for easier font handling. Since the book will most likely be offset-printed, I needed some means of color management and probably making the PDF output compliant with PDF/X, so I used the `pdfx` package. Together with the need for an XMP metadata file, many subtle problems arised from the depths of the LaTeX build process (e.g., subfont creation fails in `miktex-maketfm`, among others). I could not yet handle them, since frankly, I don't understand what is going in detail once I hit the "Compile" button in my TeX editor. When researching online, I always feel that my lack of understanding prohibits me from using the proper search terms—thus the need to learn more about pre-press in the context of my LaTeX setting.

I find it hard to get useful online material on these pre-press topics, i.e., color management, ICC profile handling, font embedding, PDF/X compliance, ... with LaTeX. **Do you have any book or other recommendations on getting a (Xe)LaTeX document ready for the print shop?** I haven't found any books on this, and reference books like "The LaTeX Companion" or the "Guide to LaTeX" seem to give at least some outlook on these questions, but even they are not too easy to obtain (at least in a printed version).

Comment: Doesn't this depend on the print shop?  I would assume they'll have some list of requirements in order to best handle a pdf.

Comment: @Teepeemm It certainly does, and some provide their requirements rightaway, some don't. However, PDF/X compliance or the use of a certain color profile are common requests. Most print shops just assume you use InDesign where this is done in a few clicks, however I was looking for a TeX-only solution. Also, I like to know what I'm doing, thus the question for further reading material.

Comment: A "TeX-only solution" is difficult, when color is involved. This is because TeX is not a graphics program (unlike InDesign, which is, and Acrobat Pro, which has built-in graphics support). If all raster images are pre-processed correctly, using external graphics software, and all vector graphics are specified and drawn correctly (this is unlikely for non-experts), then TeX can finish the job. But even then, there are many opportunities to go wrong. Bottom line: After you have the PDF, load it into Adobe Acrobat Pro (find a friend with it), and post-process to PDF/X.

Comment: @rallg After a lot of reading up, experimenting with free software, I came up with this exact "workflow". I got quite far however with Ghostscript as a post-processor for my PDF.